# Style TD like TR odd/even

Tags: css

I need to change td's text color based on odd/even, like this http://jsfiddle.net/N9gEG/

Actually I have a class which do this, but, I want to do from css

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>RED</td>
        <td class="foo">BLUE</td>
        <td>RED</td>
        <td class="foo">BLUE</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

For `tr` odd/even I have the follow code: `table tr:nth-child(even)`.

Comment: I think you'd need some Javascript for this, or give every odd cell a class, manually.

Comment: Actually I do with a manual class, need to "automatize"

Comment: @BoltClock sorry, what you mean with "Eh, select the `td`?" ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Where are you stuck? Because, as it stands currently, Boltclock's just answered your question.

Comment: @DavidThomas see http://jsfiddle.net/N9gEG/

Comment: @GabrielSantos: [so, like this](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/N9gEG/1/)?

Comment: Yes.. don't know why I don't thought of change `tr` for `td`.. I guess I need a cup of coffee.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
td {
  color: blue;
}
td:nth-child(even) {
  color: red;
}
```

This works because of rule specificity. The more specific CSS rule wins. `td` without anything else is less specific than `td:nth-child(even)`, so it applies to the odd `<td>`s automatically.

Answer (score 3):

If your jsFiddle correctly illustrates what you want, you can simply use the `:nth-child` selectors on the tds rather than the tr:

```
td { color: blue; }
td:nth-child(odd) { color: red; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N9gEG/2/

Answer (score 2):

Given my limited understanding of your question, I'd suggest:

```
td:nth-child(even) {
    color: blue;
}
td:nth-child(odd) {
    color: red;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/N9gEG/1/).

Answer (score -1):

Use jquery

```
.hover {background-color:green !important;}
.odd {background-color:blue}

$("#MyTable tr:odd").addClass("odd"); 
$("#MyTable tr").mouseover(function() { $(this).addClass("hover"); });
$("#MyTable tr").mouseout(function() { $(this).removeClass("hover"); });
```