# How can I add more than just one class to table rows in PHP?

Tags: php, css

I'm trying to fix the code of someone else. Right now I'm working on a dynamicly created table and would like to add a different class to each 2nd row. As an example the background of the 1st 3rd and 5th row should be white and the background of the 2nd 4th and 6th row grey.

Can anyone tell me how to add such 2nd class to the code?

I wasn't sure if the code would be required for this question - this is the part with a table. In case that this is not enough please let me know since my php skills are not good I'm even not sure what is need to understand the problem. As mentioned it's not my code...

```
   $arr = array();
foreach ($them as $z => $e) {
  $_them[$e['id']] = $e;
  if (count($arr) < 50) {
    $res = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `forum_comments` WHERE `id_them` = ' . $e['id'] . '');
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
    $total = $row[0];

    $arr[$e['id']] = $total;
  } else {
    $res = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `forum_comments` WHERE `id_them` = ' . $e['id'] . '');
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
    $total = $row[0];

    if ($total > $this->tools->array_val_min($arr)) {
      $arr[$this->tools->array_key_min($arr)] = $total;
    }
  }
}

arsort($arr);
$arr = array_chunk($arr, 25, true);
if (!empty($_GET['p'])) {
  $num = (int) $_GET['p'];
  if ($num == 1) {
    $arr = $arr[0];
  }
  if ($num > 1) {
    $arr = $arr[1];
  }
}

$ret = '
        <table class="forum_table">
            <tr class="forum_table_title">
                <th id="them">' . l::themes() . '</th>
                <th id="date">' . l::added() . '</th>
                <th id="users">' . l::guests() . '</th>
                <th id="commets">' . l::answers() . '</th>
                <th id="last">' . l::last_comments() . '</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="empty_td">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
    ';
```

Comment: Not unless you show the code...

Comment: Some code will be useful...

Comment: Additional classes can be separated by a space: `class="class1 class2"`

Comment: Without code, it's hard to know, but you could also look at the psuedo selectors in CSS3, especially nth-child

Comment: he has published the code. i think down votes should remove :)

Comment: @solom I TOTALLY AGREE WITH YOU !!! Hey guys you should give me some credits - I'm still new to this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use some css, it'll apply it automatically:

```
.your_table tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color:#00000; }
.your_table tr:nth-child(even) { background-color:#ffffff; }
```

Comment: & @GCyrillus & swapnesh Thanks for the replys, I didn't know that CSS has this function and finding out that there is not only (even) but also (odd) as an option was very helpfull.

Answer (score 3):

Css can do it for you :

```
tr {
       background:white;
    }
tr:nth-child(even) {
       background:grey;
    }
```

Comment: As of IE9. http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child

Comment: polyfills :) or modulo in php

Answer (score 0):

**Logical way**  -

Something like this for even - `$i%2 == 0`

**CSS Way** -

```
td {
  background: white;
}
td:nth-child(even) {
  background: grey;
}
```

Comment: who is cheating on me ;)  lol

Comment: @GCyrillus lol ..really not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827702/style-td-like-tr-odd-even  ..added logical part though

Comment: answers can't be made up anyway, it just remains the most logical CSS answer to give. We don' ow it :) just kidding , thought it was funny